# angular 6: A class declaration without the 'default' modifier must have a name

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6

I am getting this kind of error in my `ts.file`, what could be the reason in which I am just starting to learn the angular/ionic world.

---

I have tried various ways to clear it but no luck.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import {Announcements} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-our-announcements',
  templateUrl: './add-our-announcements.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-our-announcements.page.scss'],
})
@Directive({
  selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]' // Attribute selector,
})
export class {

    constructor(
      private afauth: AngularFireAuth,
      private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public navParams: NavParams,
      public element: ElementRef) {
    }

   announcements = {} as Announcements;

  @HostListener('document:keydown.enter', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler() {
    this.adjust();
  }

  AfterViewInit() {
      this.adjust();
    }

    adjust(): void {
      const textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
      textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      textArea.style.height = 'auto';
      textArea.style.height = (textArea.scrollHeight + 42) + 'px';
    }



        createAnnouncements() {
            this.afauth.authState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
              this.afDatabase.list(`announcements`).push(this.announcements)
                .then(() => this.navCtrl.navigateForward('ListOfOurAnnouncementsPage'));
            });
        }

  }
```

Comment: provide a name for your class as the error suggests. `export class MyClassNameHere`

Comment: am now getting this kind of error "The name of the class AddOurAnnouncementsPage should end with the suffix Directive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your class doesn't have a name.**
Ex:

```
@Directive({
         selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]' // Attribute selector,
     })


 export class TextAreaDirective {

     constructor() {
}
```

Please look at [how classes are defined in Typescript:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Also look at [Angular style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) for coding norms.

> Do use consistent type names for all components following a pattern that describes the component's feature then its type. A recommended pattern is feature.type.ts.
>
> **Do use conventional type names including .service, .component, .pipe,
>   .module, and .directive.** Invent additional type names if you must but
>   take care not to create too many.
>
> Why? Type names provide a consistent way to quickly identify what is
>   in the file.
>
> Why? Type names make it easy to find a specific file type using an
>   editor or IDE's fuzzy search techniques.
>
> Why? Unabbreviated type names such as .service are descriptive and
>   unambiguous. Abbreviations such as .srv, .svc, and .serv can be
>   confusing.

Comment: thank you, i just added a name into the class, and now it has brought and error "The name of the class AddOurAnnouncementsPage should end with the suffix Directive"

Comment: Yes your class name should have `Directive` attached to it. Normally your class name should end with the type of class. For ex: **a component class should have a name: `MyButtonComponent` , A directive should be `AddOurAnnouncementsDirective` and so on.**

Comment: yes i just added the directive to the name, now its alerting me "The selector of the directive "AddOurAnnouncementsPageDirective" should have prefix "app" "

Comment: Yes, These are your ts-lint rules defined in tslint.json. You can add "app" to selector EX: `selector: 'app-ion-textarea[autosize]'` or chose to disable the same by removing or modifying this rule in the tslint.json. It's a standard to have directive selectors use app, you can add any other value to it as well. For Ex: `"directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      ["myapp", "myname"],
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      ["myapp", "myname"],
      "kebab-case"
    ],`

Comment: thank you for the continuos feedback nkuma_12, i have tried both and no change to the error

Comment: try using ` [appAutosize] ` as your selector for directive.
 Selectors in Angular don't support combinators: - descendant selector (space)
- child selector (>)
- adjacent sibling selector (+)
- general sibling selector (~)

Comment: Declare Directive as one of the following: check here: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

element-name: Select by element name.
.class: Select by class name.
[attribute]: Select by attribute name.
[attribute=value]: Select by attribute name and value.
:not(sub_selector): Select only if the element does not match the sub_selector.
selector1, selector2: Select if either selector1 or selector2 matches.